# Refer to the cells above

Tags: mysql, cell

I would like help with mysql query that refers to the cell above.
for example, in the following table:

```
primary key(id)     day             count           percentage change
1                  monday             1               0  
2                  tuesday            2              (1-0)*100%=100%  
3                  wednesday          5              (2-1)*100%=100%  
4                  thursday           9              (5-2)*100%=300%  
5                  friday             27             (9-5)*100%=400%
```

The percentage change results are based on the results of the previous two days of the count column. Is there a way to incorporate the primary key(id) to refer to the cells "above"?

Comment: So Thursday's "percentage change" is the change between Tuesday and Wednesday?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not an easy way.  You need to use a self join.

```
select t.*,
       (coalesce(t_1.count, 0) - coalesce(t_2.count, 0)) * 100.0
from t left outer join
     t t_1
     on t.id = t_1.id + 1 left outer join
     t t_2
     on t.id = t_2.id + 2
```

The `left outer join` makes sure all the original rows stay, even when there are not preceding ids.

This works because the ids are sequential.  If the ids are not sequential, and the counts are monotonically increasing, you can do this with correlated subqueries:

```
select t.*,
       (coalesce((select max(`count`) as val
                  from table1 t_1
                  where t_1.`count` < t.`count`
                 ), 0)
       ) -
       (coalesce((select max(`count`)
                  from table1 t_2
                  where t_2.`count` < (select max(`count`) from table1 t_1 where t_1.`count` < t.`count`)
                 ), 0)
       )
from table1 t
```

Note:  this will not work correctly if two values are the same in a row.  For that, you would need to use the id instead:

```
select t.*,
       (coalesce((select max(`count`) as val
                  from table1 t_1
                  where t_1.`id` < t.`id`
                 ), 0)
       ) -
       (coalesce((select max(`count`)
                  from table1 t_2
                  where t_2.`id` < (select max(`id`) from table1 t_1 where t_1.`id` < t.`id`)
                 ), 0)
       )
from table1 t
```

If the counts are not increasing, then you have to get the ids, and join in the values again.  What fun!  Here is the code:

```
select t.*,
       coalesce(t1.count, 0) - coalesce(t2.count, 0)
from (select t.*,
             (select max(`id`) as id1 from table1 t_1 where t_1.`id` < t.`id`
             ) as id1,
             (select max(`count`) from table1 t_2
              where t_2.`id` < (select max(`id`) from table1 t_1 where t_1.`id` < t.`id`)
             ) id2
      from table1 t
     ) t left outer join
     table1 t1
     on t.id1 = t1.id left outer join
     table1 t2
     on t.id2 = t2.id
```

Comment: I tried this on fiddle. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9a25c/1   monday and tuesday are right, but wednesday, thursday, and friday are in the negatives. Do you know why? Also, coalesce simply means if t_1.count is null, put 0 instead of null right?

Comment: can you take a look at my new query? Instead of table t, i grouped a select and called it t. There is an error which says table t doesn't exist, which it doesn't. It is only a group. Is there a way to implement your method with a group instead of a table, t? Thanks.  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7d755/7

Comment: I have two questions. The first one is regarding the new code itself. i tried putting it into the fiddle, unfortunately there is a syntax error which I am unable to spot. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7d755/14

Comment: .....also, could you please explain your code for "correlated subqueries" when the counts are monotonically increasing? In the fiddle, the counts aren't really increasing linearly. Being a compilation of all the different data sets, each with count 1, the final count results have no apparant pattern. So pertaining to my earlier question, if I were to continue on with my code, the summation of count(1)s through grouping, would I be able to implement your method with a group instead of a table t?

Comment: @user1569897 . . . I fixed that with the last column.  You need an id or time stamp or something to specify the proper ordering of the rows.

Comment: your method refers to a table being used as the foundation for the program. is it possible to use a subquery , which takes data from the table, and name it t, then coalesce that? or use your first method to left outer join it? you can refer to this link:sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7d755/7

Comment: What you want to do is a real pain in mysql because it does not support the "with" statement.  You need to take your subquery and replace "table1" with the subquery.

Comment: do the coalesce methods support negative numbers? meaning if the "proper" result that you want returns -3, would the methods return negative 3? because right now the first few cells work perfectly, its just when the results should be a negative number, the display is 0, and every subsequent result just displays 0s.

Comment: also, how is the coalesce method 2-with id, different from the left outer join method?

Comment: Coalesce supports negative numbers.  Are you using the "id" version?  This should only return 0 when the preceding two rows are the same.  The left outer join method requires that the ids be sequential (1, 2, 3 . . .).  The correlated subquery just requires that they be in order (1, 4, 10, 200 . . .).

Comment: I tried the coalesce id method, since the values of count are sometimes the same. The example table I provided was not the full-length one. The actual table from which I extract my data actually includes counts that do not always increase. In other words, it could look something like this. 5, 6, 9, 4, 12, etc. so for the "percentage change" column, in the row where count=12, the cell should display -500%  or -5 because 4-9=-5. In the end however, I tried using the left outer join method again, because in my case, the ids are sequentially increasing by 1. It worked. So thank you.

Comment: I also added a final version that gets the largest ids, and then joins back to the table to get the counts.

Comment: how is this new version different from the first left outer join version?

Comment: The ids don't have to be sequential.  In the first outer join version, the ids had to be 1, 2, 3 and so on.  In this version, they just have to be in order, but there can be gaps.